# How calc intersection plane and line (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, intersection

I try calc intersection plane and line, but I think get wrong result.
try this code (get from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/3d_Math_functions):

```
public static bool LinePlaneIntersection(out Vector3 intersection, Vector3 linePoint, Vector3 lineVec, Vector3 planeNormal, Vector3 planePoint)
{
    float length;
    float dotNumerator;
    float dotDenominator;
    Vector3 vector;
    intersection = Vector3.zero;

    //calculate the distance between the linePoint and the line-plane intersection point
    dotNumerator = Vector3.Dot((planePoint - linePoint), planeNormal);
    dotDenominator = Vector3.Dot(lineVec, planeNormal);

    if (dotDenominator != 0.0f)
    {
        length = dotNumerator / dotDenominator;

        vector = SetVectorLength(lineVec, length);

        intersection = linePoint + vector;

        return true;
    }

    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: If you do it for the sake of learning then go on. If you plan on using it in your game then maybe you should stop right there and use Physics.Raycast/Linecast instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I think get wrong result.

Can you be more specific?

The equation you're using seems correct; although I would use `lineVec.noramlized * length` instead of that weird `SetVectorLength` function.

The basic equation for the intersection of a line and plane is point x on the line, where the value is x is given by:

```
a = (point_on_plane - point_on_line) . plane_normal
b = line_direction . plane_normal

if b is 0: the line and plane are parallel
if a is also 0: the line is exactly on the plane
otherwise: x = a / b
```

Therefore the point of intersection is: `x * line_direction + line_point`

This is exactly what your code does though... so...?

You can read more details on the wiki page here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection

Edit: Actually, it looks like this code assumes that if the dotDenominator is zero they do not intersect; partially true; if the dotNumerator is also zero the line is exactly on top of the plane, and all points intersect, so take whatever point you want as the intersection (eg. `planePoint`).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this calculation for a shader I'm writing in Unity: For the point_on_plane and point_on_line values, if my plane is centred on 0, 0, 0 can I just use the '-point_on_line' part? And is that just an arbitrary point on the line, or the 'start' or 'end'? I'm very confused...